# How can I summon Lighting in a certain spot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a little things I'm doing I need to make charged creepers. However, finding one in the wild is almost impossible and I need to have people see the creepers change into charged creepers, therefore using `/summon` to summon a charged creeper won't work. Is there a command to summon lightning?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I know almost nothing  about commands so I'm not sure what or how to try at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `/summon LightningBolt` which will hit the place that your standing.

Or the better way is to do:

```
/execute @e[type=Creeper,r=20] ~ ~ ~ /summon LightningBolt
```

Which will spawn lightning directly on all creepers within a 20 block radius.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning is an entity, and can be summoned with the summon command:

```
/summon LightningBolt
```